# Regular expression for extract numbers from the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract numbers from the string for that I have preferred the following regix

```
var str = "1 1/2 percentage";
var n = str.match(/[0-9]+([\/.]\d+)?/g);
console.log(n);
```

But I am not able to restrict negative numbers in the string .

**Valid Scenario:**

```
"1.5 % dividend applied"
"1 1/2 percentage"
 "1/10 percentage"
"2.5 percentages"
"10% dividend"
"10 percentages applied"
```

**Invalid Scenario:**

```
"-1 1/2 percentage"
"-1.5 % dividend applied"
"-10% dividend"
```

Code suggestion will be appriciated.Thank you

Comment: Should `1 / 2` match?

Comment: So, add an optional `'-'` to the beginning of your pattern.

Comment: its "1/2" its valid entry

Comment: Can you try this? ```str.match(/(?<!-)[0-9]+([\/.]\d+)?/g)```

Comment: Should `1 1/2` match as a whole, or two separated matches `1` and `1/2`?

Comment: @InSync its shoud be two ["1","1/2"]

Comment: Can you try this out ```re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+\/\d+|[-+]?\d+")```

Comment: @KarnikKanojia it have syntax issue ,not able to run

Comment: @KarnikKanojia This is not a [tag:python] question.

Comment: @InSync bellow regix will "2.25/150" as two separate  number, it should be one as"2.25/150" i am not able comment bellow so added here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
(?<![-.\d])           # Match something that is not preceded by '-', '.' or a digit,
\d+(?:\.\d+)?         # starts with a number, with or without decimal places,
(?:\/\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?  # optionally followed by '/' and another number similar to the first.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lAaAor/4).

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const testcases = [
  '1.5 % dividend applied',
  '1 1/2 percentage',
  '1/10 percentages',
  '2.5 percentages',
  '10% dividend',
  '18.6 foo',
  '10 percentages applied',
  '-1 1/2 percentage',
  '-1.5 % dividend applied',
  '-10% dividend',
  '-18.6 foo',
  '2.25/150 bar'
];

const regex = /(?<![-.\d])\d+(\.\d+)?(?:\/\d+(\.\d+)?)?/g;

for (const testcase of testcases) {
  console.log(`'${testcase}'`, testcase.match(regex) ?? 'no match');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

### Original answer

You need:

```
(?<![-.\d])   # Match something that is not preceded by '-', '.' or a digit,
\d+           # starts with 1+ digits, and
([\/.]\d+)?   # ends with either a '/' or a '.' followed by 1+ digits
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lAaAor/1).

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const testcases = [
  '1.5 % dividend applied',
  '1 1/2 percentage',
  '1/10 percentages',
  '2.5 percentages',
  '10% dividend',
  '18.6 foo',
  '10 percentages applied',
  '-1 1/2 percentage',
  '-1.5 % dividend applied',
  '-10% dividend',
  '-18.6 foo'
];

const regex = /(?<![-.\d])\d+([\/.]\d+)?/g;

for (const testcase of testcases) {
  console.log(`'${testcase}'`, testcase.match(regex) ?? 'no match');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you !,its working as expected, you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

With a mix of javascript and regex:

```
function getNumbers(text) {
    //match all numbers
    var matches = text.match(/-?\d+([\/.]\d+)?/g);
    var res = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        var match = matches[i];

        if (!match.startsWith('-')) { // check if its not a negative number
            result.push(match);
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```